# Boost python and Mac Mavericks

Tags: c++, python, boost-python, osx-mavericks

I just updated my Mac OS to Maverick and it seems to have broken something!

I am writing c++ code and using boost.python to write a python front-end.   I had working code before the upgrade and after I upgraded I started getting a strange link error:

```
darwin.link.dll /Users/Andy/software/boost-1.54.0/bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.8.1/debug/libboost_python.dylib 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: 
  "std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::size() const", referenced from: 
      boost::python::converter::(anonymous namespace)::wstring_rvalue_from_python::extract(_object*) in builtin_converters.o 
  "std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::empty() const", referenced from: 
  boost::python::converter::(anonymous namespace)::wstring_rvalue_from_python::extract(_object*) in builtin_converters.o 
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::data() const", referenced from: 
  boost::python::converter::arg_to_python<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::arg_to_python(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) in numeric.o
```

.... Pages and pages of similar errors.  Does anyone know what has happened?

Comment: It might be worth noting that I get the same link error when I try to reinstall boost.

Answer (score 0):

Where you using Xcode 5 before switching to mavericks ?

You could try to change the version of the standard library used by your project as the default in Xcode's LLVM compiler switched from C++98 to C++11.

To check it go in your target settings in xcode, "Build Settings" tab and in "Apple LLVM 5.0 - Language - C++" change :

- C++ Language Dialect from "Compiler default" to "GNU++98"
- C++ Standard Library from "Compiler default" to "libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)"